# Is the Earth's molten outer core affecting its motion?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, kinematics, earth

According with the [seismological studies [1]](http://www.amnh.org/education/resources/rfl/web/essaybooks/earth/p_lehmann.html) the outer core, with thickness of about $2300km$, starting from depth of $2,900 km$ and ending at $5,200 km$ is a low viscosity fluid, consisted mostly of iron and nickel.

Considering the above, what are <sup>if any</sup> the implications of the internal degrees of freedom of the liquid outer core, to the Earth's motion<sup>1</sup>?

---

<sup>1. In any of the components: rotation around own axis, precession, and around the Sun.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Brief answer: There will be no change in the motion.

Let's think about earth's mass, the outer core of the earth will be burnt with that very   hot liquid <sup>(in fact it is not liquid and it is called plasma)</sup> and most part of the Earth's core will change phase to gas and the lightest gas molecules will escape from the Earth's atmosphere to the space. Then the Earth will start to be lighter and lighter. It means the mass of the Earth ($m$) will start to decrease continuously.

Now, let's think about physical properties: the Sun pulls the earth with force of: 
       $$F_(gravity)=G \frac{M * m }{ R^2}$$

Here is $M$ is the mass of the Sun and Earth is making circular motion around the Sun. Then the Earth will experience a centripetal force of:

$$F(centripetal) = \frac{mv^2}{R}$$

Then

$$F_(gravity) = F_(centripetal)$$

$$G\frac{Mm}{R^2} =  \frac{mv^2}{R}$$

will change to:

$$G \frac{M}{R} = v^2$$

As you see the mass of the Earth is independent of its velocity, consequently I think the we can say that nothing about the motion of Earth around the Sun will change. Additionally, I think we can't say anything about the motion of Earth rotation around its own axis.

Summarizing, there will be no implication from the plasma inside Earth's core.

Comment: The other properties won't affect the motion of earth

Comment: *And I think we can't say anything about the motion of earth rotation around own axis.* Why not? If anything, I'd assume that the earth's rotation would be affected moreso than earth's orbit about Sol.

Comment: @user101844 Your answer considers the motion( independence of change in) Earth's mass. To put you more in the context I'm thinking of, imagine rotating/throwing two eggs, one is boiled one is raw, will there be any difference in their rotation/trajectory (projectile motion)?

Comment: A complete answer would discuss the rotational evolution, which might be affected by fluid zones.

Comment: @simplicisveritatis no

Answer (score 0):

The more the core plasma cools and is harden into crust, Earths axis spin will decrease,and vise versa.The moons and the earth spin in the same direction so the gravitational tug by the moon helps to keep a constant axis spin speed even though the plasma core is slowly depleting.